# Python 3, how to scrape webpages and filter for Href's, delete rubbish and sort

Tags: python, html, file, http, urllib

Only interested in Python 3, this is a lab for school and we aren't using Python2.

Tools
Python 3 and
Ubuntu

I want to first be able to download webpages of my choosing, e.g. www.example.com/index.html

and save the index.html or what ever page I want.

Then do the following bash

```
grep Href cut -d"/" -f3 sort -u
```

But do this in python not using grep, wget, cut etc... but instead only using python 3 commands.

Also, not using any python scrappers such as scrapy etc... NO legacy python commands no urllib2

so I was thinking to start with,

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError,URLError
o = urllib.request.urlopen(www.example.com/index.html) #should I use http://  ?

local_file = open(file_name, "w" + file_mode)
        #Then write to my local file
        local_file.write(o.read())
        local_file.close()

except HTTPError as e:
            print("HTTP Error:",e.code , url)
except URLError as e:
            print("URL Error:",e.reason , url)
```

But I still need to filter out the href's from the file, and delete all the other stuff, how do i do that, and is the above code ok ?

I thought urllib.request would be better than urlretrieve because it was faster, but if you think that there is not much different maybe it's better to use urlretrieve ?

Comment: `o = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.example.com/index.html")`

Answer (score 2):

There is a python package called [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which does what you need.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

My try. Kept it as simple as I could (thus, not very efficient for an actual crawler)

```
from urllib import request

# Fetch the page from the url we want
page = request.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
# print(page)

def get_link(page):
    """ Get the first link from the page provided """
    tag = 'href="'
    tag_end   = '"'
    tag_start = page.find(tag)
    if not tag_start == -1:
         tag_start += len(tag)
    else:
        return None, page
    tag_end   = page.find(tag_end, tag_start)
    link = page[tag_start:tag_end]
    page = page[tag_end:]
    return link, page

def get_all_links(page):
    """ Get all the links from the page provided by calling get_link """
    all_links = []
    while True:
        link, page = get_link(page)
        if link:
            all_links.append(link)
        else:
            break
    return all_links

print(get_all_links(page))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You can read a post where everything you need is explained:
- Download a web page
- Using beautifulSoup
- Extrac something you need

Extract HTML code from URL in Python and C# - http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/1/extract-html-code-url-python-c